# how to existing Id to set it to another table add it as foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi All I have the following tables 
**Tables**

```
root(id,fromCity,toCity ) id-primary

Vehicle(id,number,rootId) id-prim , rootId-foreign(id in root table)
```

In Html page I have drop down list for "CityFrom" and "CityTo" , text box for vehicle 
so In servlet I am getting  CityFrom CityTo Vehicle details..

```
for every new request i have to see 
1. the route exist already in route table set rootId to vehicle table .. 
2.If root not exist I have to add root to Root table then set that id in vehicle table
```

So every time i am checking for root exist and adding that id to vehicle using Hibernate .. I feel it is hard coding

Is there any any Alternative in **Hibernate** which automatically searches for rootId in root Table and set it to Vehicle table

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing that using hibernate, but you are going in the right path.

I'm assuming that **cascade=ALL** is used on the joincolumns.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Root where fromCity = :from and toCity =:to ");
query.setParameter("from", "7277");
query.setParameter("to", "7277");

Root r = query.uniqueResult();

if(r==null){
     r = new Root(from,to);
}

vehicle.setRoot(r);
session.saveOrUpdate(r); //this will create vehicleId and root id if not present and sets the foreign key also for you
```

Comment: tq @Zeus . I just tried out with your code and here got a problem ..for Root pojo class(bean class) i did not set any autogeneration for id (i.e @GeneratedValue)..so to save new ROOT if I set null to id(primary key) then it is not saving and giving me error that id must be manually assigned.. can you solve this ..

Comment: Can you post your code in the question. ie., entity and the place where the save?